# Setting checked to true based on URL value

Tags: javascript

I'm passing a value from a form to a page.

The url is: http://url.com/page?land1=value

Or if empty it is just: http://url.com/page

I have a checkbox on this page, with the code:

```
<input id="Nederland" name="interest8" type="checkbox">
<label for="Nederland">
     <div class="checkbox-text">
          Nederland
     </div>
</label>
```

Then my JS to check whether the URL contains a `land1` value:

```
  function getCheckboxwaardes(){
    var url_string = window.location.href;
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var land1 = url.searchParams.get("land1");
    var land1_input = document.getElementById('Nederland');
      if (land1 !== "") {land1_input.checked = true;}
  }
```

This function pretty much works, but the problem is that it only checks if `land1` isn't empty. It doesn't check if the URL even contains `land1`. Does someone know how to do this double check?

So if `land1` even exists and THEN if it does exist, if it isn't empty and then check the checkbox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `if(land1) {}` This way it will check if land1 exist or not that is null, and empty both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`url.searchParams.get(key)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get) returns a string if the given search parameter is found; otherwise, `null`. So you can simply update your if condition like:

```
if (land1) {
   land1_input.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Or `land1_input.checked = !!land1`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are getting confused with conditionals. Rephrase your question to gain better understanding of your doubt.

Made changes to your `getCheckboxwaardes` down below:

```
function getCheckboxwaardes(){
    var url_string = window.location.href;
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var land1 = url.searchParams.get("land1");
    var land1_input = document.getElementById('Nederland');
      if (land1 === "land1") {land1_input.checked = true;}
      if (land1 === "") {land1_input.checked = false;}
  }
```

Comment: What if *land1* is undefined or null? Then neither of the conditions will be true.

Comment: Oh, I forgot null and undefine Javascript behaviour. JS without type system is an abomination

Answer (score 0):

```
land1_input.checked = land1 ? true : false
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so you can get more upvotes for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will take care for null, "", undefined and all the falsy conditions

`and1_input.checked = land1 ? true : false`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function getCheckboxwaardes(){
    const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    var land1_input = document.getElementById('Nederland');
    land1_input.checked = query.get('land1') ? true : false;
  }
```

> It is simple and neat :)